# Можно ли удалить корень бинарного древа?

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Сегодня изучал бинарное древо поиска и натолкнулся на мысль: а что если потребуется удалить один элемент дерева и он же является корнем. Каким образом можно осуществить это, если вовсе возможно? Т.е удалить этот элемент, назначив на какой-нибудь еще, дабы древо и далее функционировало(прошу теоретическую часть, а не готовый код)

Comment: Имеете в виду [бинарное дерево *поиска*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)?

Comment: Да, дерево поиска

Comment: Почему бы просто не сказать, что `Node *root = nullptr`? Если у вас реализация на указателях.

Comment: Разве после этого я смогу и далее получать доступ к информации что хранится в нем?

Comment: Вот тут есть алгоритм: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0_(REMOVE)

Comment: Если я правильно помню, обычно в деревьях чтобы удалить какую-то вершину, её утапливают в самый низ дерева так, чтобы его структура сохранилась правильной, и оттуда удаляют.

Comment: Подойдёт точно такой же алгоритм, как и удаление любой другой вершины

Answer (score 0):

Тогда вы будете копировать элемент, который станет на место корня, удаляете корень и  вставляете  новый элемент